# How to merge two lists using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

How to merge two lists using LINQ like the following:

```
class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public Person Merge( Person p)
    {
         return new Person { ID = this.ID, Name = this.Name + " " + p.Name };
    } 
}
```

I have two List of person:

```
list1:
1, A
2, B

list2: 
2, C
3, D
```

I want the result like the following

```
result: 
1, A
2, B C
3, D
```

Any help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against using string-concatenation to represent this information; you will need to perform unnecessary string-manipulation if you want to get  the original data back later from the merged list. Additionally, the merged version (as it stands) will become lossy if you ever decide to add additional properties to the class.

Preferably, get rid of the `Merge` method and use an appropriate data-structure such as a multimap that can each map a collection of keys to one or more values. The [`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class can serve this purpose:

```
var personsById = list1.Concat(list2)
                       .ToLookup(person => person.ID);
```

---

Anyway, to answer the question as asked, you can concatenate the two sequences, then group persons by their `ID` and then aggregate each group into a *single* person with the provided `Merge` method:

```
var mergedList = list1.Concat(list2)
                      .GroupBy(person => person.ID)
                      .Select(group => group.Aggregate(
                                         (merged, next) => merged.Merge(next)))
                      .ToList();
```

**EDIT**: Upon re-reading, just realized that a concatenation is required since there are *two* lists.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the posted code is just a sample for the idea, not my real code.