# How to optimize function for merging sorted arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I write this function for merging two arrays.

```
private static int[] Merge(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    var mergedArray = new int[array1.Length + array2.Length];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while(k < mergedArray.Length)
    {
        if(i == array1.Length || j == array2.Length)
        {
             if (i <= j)
                {
                    mergedArray[k] = array1[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    mergedArray[k] = array2[j];
                    j++;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            if(array1[i] < array2[j])
            {
                mergedArray[k] = array1[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                mergedArray[k] = array2[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    return mergedArray;
}
```

How to reduce if statements in this code?

Comment: This is not the same question. The merging here takes into account the values of the arrays, while the possible duplicate only concatenates two arrays.

Comment: I think this does more than just merge. Maybe there some sorting going on (`if(array1[i]<array2[j])..` statement). Can you please explain more what are you trying to do.

Comment: Yes. I use this merging for merge-sort. Please vote for reopen.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you were trying to do a merge-sort. If the question had been clearer, I wouldn't have voted to close.

Comment: _"Is there a way to simplify this code?"_ --> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807701/is-there-an-easy-way-to-merge-two-ordered-sequences-using-linq

Comment: @Victor: Please provide an example set of arrays, and what the expected results are. The intent is not clear from the source what the `Merge()` function _actually_ does.

Comment: Here's another Merge-Sort question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7717871/284240

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient algorithm for merging sorted IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767007/most-efficient-algorithm-for-merging-sorted-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not as good as the Linq solution, but if you want the traditional if-then style function you could write:

```
private static int[] Merge(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    var mergedArray = new int[array1.Length + array2.Length];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while(k < mergedArray.Length)
    {
        if (j == array2.Length || ((i < array1.Length) && (array[i] < array2[j])))
        {
            mergedArray[k] = array1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            mergedArray[k] = array2[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return mergedArray;
}
```

(edit: missing brace added)

#### Or in English:

If array2 is empty or if there are still values in array 1 and array1[i] is less than array2[j], then take value from array1, otherwise take from array 2

#### Or very concise (just for fun):

```
private static int[] Merge(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    var mergedArray = new int[array1.Length + array2.Length];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i+j < mergedArray.Length)
        if (j == array2.Length || ((i < array1.Length) && (array1[i] < array2[j])))
            mergedArray[i+j] = array1[i++];
        else
            mergedArray[i+j] = array2[j++];
    return mergedArray;
}
```

Comment: This is much better than the Linq solution (you can measure the speed if you want). That said you must put the `j == array2.Length` test at the beginning of your test. ie `if (j == array2.Length || ((i < array1.Length) && (array[i] < array2[j])))` otherwise, array2[j] could throw an exception

Comment: Would this also assume that the two arrays passed in as parameters are already ordered?

Comment: @ErikPhilips the question asker assumes so, yes

Comment: @jcolebrand I feel like i'm blind, where did he mention the arrays are pre-sorted?

Comment: the title `How to optimize function for merging sorted arrays in C#`

Answer (score 12):

You can also make a Linq friendly version. This one is fast and will work on IEnumerable.
You could easily translate this to any type T where T is IComparable.

```
    private static IEnumerable<int> Merge(IEnumerable<int> enum1, IEnumerable<int> enum2)
    {
        IEnumerator<int> e1 = enum1.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<int> e2 = enum2.GetEnumerator();

        bool remaining1 = e1.MoveNext();
        bool remaining2 = e2.MoveNext();

        while (remaining1 || remaining2)
        {
            if (remaining1 && remaining2)
            {
                if (e1.Current > e2.Current)
                {
                    yield return e2.Current;
                    remaining2 = e2.MoveNext();
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return e1.Current;
                    remaining1 = e1.MoveNext();
                }
            }
            else if (remaining2)
            {
                yield return e2.Current;
                remaining2 = e2.MoveNext();
            }
            else
            {
                yield return e1.Current;
                remaining1 = e1.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Linq is your friend, here is one way:

```
private static int[] Merge(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
  List<int> merged = new List<int>(array1.Length + array2.Length);
  merged.AddRange(array1);
  merged.AddRange(array2);
  return merged.GroupBy(x => x)
               .Select(x => x.Key)
               .OrderBy(x => x)
               .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: `Array.Copy(array1, newArray, array1.Length);`

Comment: I think that arrays more faster than Lists

Comment: @Victor You can entirely avoid copy if you yous `array1.Concat(array2)` instead of `merge`. Linq consumes anyway 'IEnumerable' so the `Concat` will first enumerate through `array1` and then through `array2`.

Comment: @Victor if the two arrays can contain the same values, this solution **removes the duplicates**. So while your `Merge(new [] {2,3,4}, new [] {4,5,6})` will results in 2,3,4,4,5,6 until Erik's solution results in 2,3,4,5,6

Comment: @Victor By the way is avoiding conditionals really your ultimative goal? You solution has `O(n)` time - with proposed Linq you will get `O(n log(n))` because it involves `OrderBy`. Are you really happy with the trade-off?

Comment: I agree with achitaka, this solution is terrible. It would be eaasy to write a merge function for two IEnumerable though

Answer (score 2):

Rather than being specific to arrays, I'd suggest looking at the following question for a number of different answers for `IEnumerable<T>`. [Most efficient algorithm for merging sorted IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767007/most-efficient-algorithm-for-merging-sorted-ienumerablet/14444706#14444706)

The answer I provided at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444706/184528 has only one `if` statement and merge multiple enumerables.

For example to use it to merge three different arrays:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xs = new[] { 1, 5, 9 };
        var ys = new[] { 2, 7, 8 };
        var zs = new[] { 0, 3, 4, 6 };

        foreach (var a in new [] { xs, ys, zs }.Merge())
            Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is the most "reduced" version of the function:

```
private static int[] Merge(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    return array1.Concat(array2).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
}
```

It can't get much simpler than this. Not one `if` remaining.

I ran this `Merge(new [] { 1, 2, 2, 3 }, new [] { 1, 1, 2, 4, })` on both the original code and my solution and got the same answer.

Answer (score -1):

How about using `Queue<int>` to drain the arrays:

```
    private static int[] Merge(int[] array1, int[] array2)
    {
        int N=array1.Length+array2.Length;
        Queue<int> Q1=new Queue<int>(array1);
        Queue<int> Q2=new Queue<int>(array2);
        Queue<int> result=new Queue<int>(N);

        for(int k=0; k<N; k++)
        {
            if(Q1.Count==0)
            {
                result.Enqueue(Q2.Dequeue());
            }
            else if(Q2.Count==0)
            {
                result.Enqueue(Q1.Dequeue());
            }
            else
            {
                result.Enqueue(
                    Q1.Peek()<Q2.Peek()?
                    Q1.Dequeue():
                    Q2.Dequeue());
            }
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: You are copying arrays at least 3 times.