# Merge contents of multiple lists of custom objects - C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a class Project as

```
public class Project 
{   public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}
```

and I have 3 lists

```
List<Project> lst1; List<Project> lst2; List<Project> lst3;
```

`lst1` contains `Person` objects with ProjectId and ProjectName.

`ProjectId =1, ProjectName = "X", Customer = null, Address = null`

`ProjectId =2, ProjectName = "Y", Customer = null, Address = null`

`lst2` contains `Person` objects with ProjectId and Customer

`ProjectId =1,ProjectName = null, Customer = "c1", Address = null`

`ProjectId =2,ProjectName = null, Customer = "c2", Address = null`
, and

`lst3` contains `Person` objects with ProjectId and Address

`ProjectId = 1, ProjectName = null, Customer =null, Address = "a1"`

`ProjectId = 2, ProjectName = null, Customer =null, Address = "a2"`.

Considering there are multiple such records in each list and ProjectId is Uniqe for each project, How can I merge/combine these list to get one list with merged objects

`ProjectId=1, ProjectName="X", Customer="c1", address="a1"`

`ProjectId=2, ProjectName="Y", Customer="c2", address="a2"`

I found thse links similar and tried with it but could not meet the results

[Create a list from two object lists with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720609/merge-two-object-lists-with-linq)

[How to merge two lists using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872943/how-to-merge-two-lists-using-linq)

Thank You.

Comment: In each list, is there always (besides projectId) exactly one property not null?

Comment: And is there a fixed set of properties, known in advance?

Comment: @phg : No. to both questions. This is just example.
And also lists may not contain same number of records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done in a multi-step approach pretty simply. First, define a `Func<Project, Project, Project>` to handle the actual record merging. That is, you are defining a method with a signature equivalent to `public Project SomeMethod(Project p1, Project p2)`. This method implements the merging logic you outlined above. Next, we concatenate the elements of the lists together before grouping them by `ProjectId`, using our merge delegate as the an aggregate function in the overload of `GroupBy` which accepts a result selector:

```
Func<Project, Project, Project> mergeFunc = (p1,p2) => new Project
    {
        ProjectId = p1.ProjectId,
        ProjectName = p1.ProjectName == null ? p2.ProjectName : p1.ProjectName,
        Customer = p1.Customer == null ? p2.Customer : p1.Customer,
        Address = p1.Address == null ? p2.Address : p1.Address    
    };

var output = lst1.Concat(lst2).Concat(lst3)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.ProjectId, (k, g) => g.Aggregate(mergeFunc));
```

Here's a quick and dirty test of the above logic along with output:

```
List<Project> lst1; List<Project> lst2; List<Project> lst3;
lst1 = new List<Project> 
    {
        new Project { ProjectId = 1, ProjectName = "P1" },
        new Project { ProjectId = 2, ProjectName = "P2" },
        new Project { ProjectId = 3, ProjectName = "P3" }
    };
lst2 = new List<Project>
    {
        new Project { ProjectId = 1, Customer = "Cust1"},
        new Project { ProjectId = 2, Customer = "Cust2"},
        new Project { ProjectId = 3, Customer = "Cust3"}
    };
lst3 = new List<Project>
    {
        new Project { ProjectId = 1, Address = "Add1"},
        new Project { ProjectId = 2, Address = "Add2"},
        new Project { ProjectId = 3, Address = "Add3"}
    };

Func<Project, Project, Project> mergeFunc = (p1,p2) => new Project
    {
        ProjectId = p1.ProjectId,
        ProjectName = p1.ProjectName == null ? p2.ProjectName : p1.ProjectName,
        Customer = p1.Customer == null ? p2.Customer : p1.Customer,
        Address = p1.Address == null ? p2.Address : p1.Address    
    };

var output = lst1
    .Concat(lst2)
    .Concat(lst3)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ProjectId, (k, g) => g.Aggregate(mergeFunc));

IEnumerable<bool> assertedCollection = output.Select((x, i) => 
    x.ProjectId == (i + 1) 
    && x.ProjectName == "P" + (i+1) 
    && x.Customer == "Cust" + (i+1) 
    && x.Address == "Add" + (i+1));

Debug.Assert(output.Count() == 3);  
Debug.Assert(assertedCollection.All(x => x == true));
```

--- output ---

```
IEnumerable<Project> (3 items)   
ProjectId ProjectName Customer Address 
1 P1 Cust1 Add1 
2 P2 Cust2 Add2 
3 P3 Cust3 Add3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a Lookup you can do it like this:

```
        List<Project> lst = lst1.Union(lst2).Union(lst3).ToLookup(x => x.ProjectId).Select(x => new Project()
        {
            ProjectId = x.Key,
            ProjectName = x.Select(y => y.ProjectName).Aggregate((z1,z2) => z1 ?? z2),
            Customer = x.Select(y => y.Customer).Aggregate((z1, z2) => z1 ?? z2),
            Address = x.Select(y => y.Address).Aggregate((z1, z2) => z1 ?? z2)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank You. I think I need to search how ToLookup works.

Comment: although this solution works, you don't need to project the properties prior to aggregation. See my answer for how you can do the same thing in a bit more of a readable fashion. The lookup is also optional, and is roughly equivalent to the GroupBy in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that list contains same number of items and are sorted by ProjectId.

```
List<Project> lst1; List<Project> lst2; List<Project> lst3
```

If list are not sorted you can sort it first.

```
list1.Sort(p => p.ProjectId);
list2.Sort(p => p.ProjectId);
list3.Sort(p => p.ProjectId);
```

For merging the object

```
List<Project> list4 = new List<Project>();
for(int i=1; i<list.Count; i++)
{ 
    list4.Add(new Project
    {
       ProjectId = list1[i].ProjectId;
       ProjectName = list1[i].ProjectName;
       Customer = list2[i].Customer;
       Address = list3[i].Address;
    });

}
```

Comment: This is a nice simple way of doing things if the items are all in the right order.

Comment: lists may not contain same number of records. And even if they have same records ProjectId may differ.

Comment: Then on which criteria you will merge them?

Comment: @Asif : Every list will have some projects with ProjectId, So for each projectId I want to gather data from different lists and make a single list.

Answer (score 1):

I belive the folloing is how LINQ `Join` works:

```
var mergedProjects =
    lst1
        .Join(lst2,
            proj1 => proj1.ProjectID,
            proj2 => proj2.ProjectID,
            (proj1, proj2) => new { Proj1 = proj1, Proj2 = proj2 })
        .Join(lst3,
            pair => pair.Proj1.ProjectID,
            proj3 => proj3.ProjectID,
            (pair, proj3) => new Project
            {
                ProjectID = proj3.ProjectID,
                ProjectName = pair.Proj1.ProjectName,
                Customer = pair.Proj2.Customer,
                Address = proj3.Address
            });
```

This will not return any results where the `ProjectID` is not found in *all three lists*.

If this is a problem, I think you'd be better off doing this manually rather than using LINQ.

Comment: although this addresses the OP question, it does so pretty narrowly. This solution would seem a bit brittle. It would be better, IMO, if the code made the merging logic explicit in the operation instead of assuming that `projXX.PropXX` maps in a particular way (no downvote, BTW, just an observation)

Comment: @Josh The question was pretty specific about each property coming from a given list, less so about all IDs being present in each list. It would have been clearer to collate all the items with a given ID into a single anonymous object and then gather the properties as a final step, rather than gather the properties one-by-one. This isn't very extensible if you have other lists with other properties, or more than one property per list, but these weren't stated in the original question.

Comment: there's always 1...N ways to skin a cat, right? Fair points you make.

Answer (score 1):

Although overkill, I was tempted to make this an extension method:

```
public static List<T> MergeWith<T,TKey>(this List<T> list, List<T> other, Func<T,TKey> keySelector, Func<T,T,T> merge)
{
    var newList = new List<T>();
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        var otherItem = other.SingleOrDefault((i) => keySelector(i).Equals(keySelector(item)));
        if(otherItem != null)
        {
            newList.Add(merge(item,otherItem));
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Usage would then be:

```
var merged = list1
     .MergeWith(list2, i => i.ProjectId,
       (lhs,rhs) => new Project{ProjectId=lhs.ProjectId,ProjectName=lhs.ProjectName, Customer=rhs.Customer})
    .MergeWith(list3,i => i.ProjectId,
       (lhs,rhs) => new Project{ProjectId=lhs.ProjectId,ProjectName=lhs.ProjectName, Customer=lhs.Customer,Address=rhs.Address});
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/ETIVB14254

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Thank You. Just one thing, why overkill ? I mean in terms of performance or what ?

Comment: It's overkill because it is a bit of a complex solution to a relatively simple problem (@Jamiec - that what you meant?). Also, the manner of which the merging is accomplished will result/could result in multiple executions of the same query expression. Finally, there are other operators (namely `.Zip()`) that duplicate some (but not all) this functionality.

Comment: @JoshE - pretty much exactly. I wrote this rather quick, and just knew there would be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you want to take the first non-null value, or revert to the default value - in this case null for a string.

```
private static IEnumerable<Project> GetMergedProjects(IEnumerable<List<Project>> projects)
{
    var projectGrouping = projects.SelectMany(p => p).GroupBy(p => p.ProjectId);
    foreach (var projectGroup in projectGrouping)
    {
        yield return new Project
                            {
                                ProjectId = projectGroup.Key,
                                ProjectName =
                                    projectGroup.Select(p => p.ProjectName).FirstOrDefault(
                                        p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p)),
                                Customer =
                                    projectGroup.Select(c => c.Customer).FirstOrDefault(
                                        c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)),
                                Address =
                                    projectGroup.Select(a => a.Address).FirstOrDefault(
                                        a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)),
                            };
    }
}
```

You could also make this an extension method if needed.