# Show comma-separated string in datalist or listview?

Tags: c#, listview, asp.net-4.0

I have string which has data in comma-separated format. like below.

```
xyz,abc,lmnk
```

Now I need to show these items in one of the column in listview or datalist but like below (vertically).

```
xyz
abc
lmnk
```

How to do? Not able to figure out.

I have other columns to show in listview and my listview in bind with custom object. Like below.

```
List<Product> p =GetProductlist();
        lvProduct.DataSource = p;
```

And now in my listview i am showing the content of list like

```
<a> '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductName")%>'</a>
                           <a> '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductIntegraidents")%>'</a>
```

and here the ProuctInegraident contains the comma seprated text.

Comment: Split on the comma, store in a collection, set the datasource of datalist/view to the collection, call databind on datalist/view.

Comment: Here's how to add items to a Listview (first search result):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951704/add-item-to-listview-control

Comment: var myresult = mycomastring.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: Ok i have updated my question. Please guide me now.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872943/how-to-merge-two-lists-using-linq

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
myListView.DataSource = myString.Split(',');
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please guide me on that. I am binding custom list and one property contains comma separated text.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got the answer.

```
<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("ProductIntegraidents")).Replace(",","<br/>") %
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method:

```
var str = "xyz,abc,lmnk";
var items = str.Split(new char[] { ',' });
```

Then you can use the returned value as the `DataSource`:

```
var listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.DataSource = items;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use following code:**

```
ListView.Items.Add(myString.Split(','));
```

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method;

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified Unicode character array.

```
var s = "xyz,abc,lmnk";
var i = s.Split(new char[] { ',' });

foreach(var z in i)
   Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/VkGmCn).

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "xyz,abc,lmnk";
String[] Splitted = str.Split(',');
foreach (var word in Splitted)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
        listView1.Items.Add(word);
}
```

Something like that, use an ListViewItem if you want more 'control', for example adding subitems etc.