# How to Merge two lists and Merge it's inner lists without duplication in C#

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

I'm trying to merge two generic list using LINQ-

```
List<LinkedTable> FirstLink
List<LinkedTable> SecondLink
```

As shown in the Class below, my generic list itself has a generic list in it.

```
public class LinkedTable
{
    public string TableId { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public List<Link> innerLinks { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public Boolean linkFlag;
    public string Descriptor { get; set; }
    public string RecordId { get; set; }
}
```

When I merge the two lists, the new list doesn't contain both the "innerLinks" records of FirstLink and SecondLink.
I have tried the following code:

```
FirstLink = FirstLink.Concat(SecondLink)
                     .GroupBy(e1 => e1.TableId)
                     .Select(e2 => e2.FirstOrDefault())
                     .ToList();
```

Now FirstLink will get all the Tables grouped by "TableId ", but a few "innerLinks" from SecondLink is missing.

I need both the list of "innerLinks" from FirstLink and SecondLink in the new merged List without repetition.

Example:

```
FirstLink[0].innerLinks[0]
            .innerLinks[1]
            .innerLinks[2]

SecondLink[0].innerLinks[1]
             .innerLinks[2]
             .innerLinks[3]
```

Merged Link should be:

```
FirstLink[0].innerLinks[0]
            .innerLinks[1]
            .innerLinks[2]            
            .innerLinks[3]
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `foreach (var item in SecondLink){FirstLink.Add(item);}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two lists using LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872943/how-to-merge-two-lists-using-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option:

First, you'll have to provide a way to tell Linq what makes a Link equal to another. You can do this by any of this methods:

- creating a class the implements `IEqualityComparer<Link>` and pass an instance of it as parameter to `Distinct`;
- implementing `IEquatable<Link>` and overriding `GetHashCode` on the Link class
- overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on the Link class.

Assuming that RecordId is the unique identifier for a Link object, this is how you do it by implementing `IEquatable<Link>`:

```
public class Link : IEquatable<Link>
{
    public Boolean linkFlag;
    public string Descriptor { get; set; }
    public string RecordId { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Link other)
    {
        //Adjust for a suiting identifier and do all the sanity checks, if needed.
        return this.RecordId == other.RecordId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //You can also use another GetHash approach that suits you better.
        return this.RecordId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then, you can `Concat` both lists, then group by TableId and TableName. Last, you use `SelectMany` on the grouped LinkedTable's innerLinks to select all Links contained on that group. The `Distinct` will have to take an instance of the `IEqualityComparer` in case you opted to go that way.

```
var merged = 
    from item in FirstLink.Concat(SecondLink)
    group item by new { Id = item.TableId, Name = item.TableName } into tbGp
    select new LinkedTable
    {
        TableId = tbGp.Key.Id,
        TableName = tbGp.Key.Name,
        innerLinks = tbGp.SelectMany(p => p.innerLinks).Distinct().ToList()
    };
```

`Distinct` and `IEquatable<T>` explained [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2/)
Overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't work because when you are grouping you are taking the first element of the Group and **its list of `Link` objects**.

To achieve your result you should try the following code:

```
var FirstLink = FirstLink
    .Concat(SecondLink)
    .GroupBy(e1 => e1.TableId)
    // Don't take the first item, but create a new one with the items you need
    .Select(e2 => new LinkedTable
        {
            TableId = e2.Key,
            TableName = e2.First().TableName,
            innerLinks = e2.SelectMany(x => x.innerLinks).ToList()
        })
    .ToList();
```